# ResponseEntity returning java.lang.Object

Tags: java, json, rest, controller, resttemplate

I have this service that takes certain users from a db and returns them as a json object. 
I want to receive the response and use it as a json but I'm almost 100% sure that I did something wrong cause if I print the response I get this:

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@69a38065
```

**This is the controller:**

```
    public Object[] getClienteNomeCognome(String nome, String cognome) throws Exception {
    try {
        final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        final String url = "somelink?cognome=%25"+cognome+"%25&nome=%25"+nome+"%25";
        //final ResponseEntity<List> response = (ResponseEntity<List>) restTemplate.getForObject(url, List.class);
        final ResponseEntity<Object[]> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, Object[].class);
        Object[] risultati = response.getBody();
        LOGGER.info("La richiesta e' stata effettuata con status code: " + response.getStatusCode().toString());
        if (risultati != null && risultati.toString().contains("<error>")) {
            throw new Exception(String.format(
                    "[SERVICE] La risposta del servizio contiene degli errori: %s",
                    risultati));
        } else {
            LOGGER.debug("[SERVICE] Fine chiamata al servizio di ricerca cliente");
            LOGGER.info(response.getBody().toString());
            return risultati;
        }
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException hcee) {
        throw new Exception(String.format(
                "[SERVICE] Errore durante la chiamata. Error: %s",
                hcee.getMessage()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(String.format(
                "[SERVICE] Errore generico durante la chiamata al servizio. Error: %s",
                        e.getMessage()));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are displaying the toString() result, which has not been overloaded on Object class. Thus it displays the object's name plus the address.

You should use a class to store the results, and you can overload toString() to have a meaningful representation.

Also you can use a strongly typed list to display the results:

```
ResponseEntity<List<YourEntity>> yourResponse = restTemplate.exchange("https://some-link/your-object-location",
                HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<YourEntity>>() {
        });
List<YourEntity> entities = yourResponse .getBody();
```

Comment: I'd prefer not to implement a class because I'm not sure about what information the service will return so I need a solution that lets me operate with a json object so I could recover information with something like an angular ngrepeat...